# Stop a funtion from running with ClearTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons to start and stop the progress bar. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0   /jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form  name="Calculation" method="post">

<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;">    </progress>

<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Start Acquisition" onclick="progressBarSim(0)">

<input type="button" value="Stop Acquisition" onclick="myStopFunction()">

</form>

<script>

function progressBarSim(al) {

var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');

bar.value = al;

al++;

 var sim = setTimeout(function(){  progressBarSim(al); }, 50);

}

function myStopFunction() {
clearTimeout(sim);
}

</script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

I want to make the progress to stop  with the "Stop Acquisition" button during the time that the progress is running. I guess ClearTimeout would only work when the progress is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct with a small update. You need to declare the variable outside the function. You need to update script to following

```
var sim; // outside the function
function progressBarSim(al) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
    bar.value = al;
    al++;
    sim = setTimeout(function(){  progressBarSim(al); }, 50);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(sim);
}
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/F88fYlOklpayfnWNWh9l?p=preview

Comment: It works for me. I have added plunker in answer for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to  remove the var from setTimeout...Thank you again.